# cuModuleLoadDataEx options

Tags: cuda

I'm trying my hands at JIT compilation of PTX code.
The code compiles and runs, but excruciatingly slowly compared to the cuda C it is generated from.
Trying to experiment why running the PTX code generated from cuda C is slower (both targeting compute_20/sm_20), i wanted to set options in my call cuModuleLoadDataEx to ensure it is targeting compute_20/sm_20, but i can't seem to pass the options correctly.
currently i have

```
CUjit_option options[] = {
    CU_JIT_TARGET
}
CUjit_target_enum target = CU_TARGET_COMPUTE_20
void *optionValues[] = {
    &target
};
int32_t err = cuModuleLoadDataEx(&hModule, ptxSrc, 1, options, optionValues);
```

but the call returns 1 (cudaErrorMissingConfiguration)
I have of course tried searching for examples of how to correctly set options, both on stack overflow and google, but i can't find any.
the call succeeds and the code runs correctly if i don't try to set any options.

Comment: Shouldn't  `options` be passed as a pointer, and the `optionValues` as a pointer-to-pointer?

Comment: Have you tried using inline PTX instead?

Answer (score 1):

Search the sample programs that come with the CUDA SDK, and you'll find a number of examples of cuModuleLoadDataEx, although none of them seems to specify CU_JIT_TARGET.  I see this function call in matrixMulDrv, vectorAddDrv, and a few others.

Looking at those samples, it seems that when the optionvalue needs to be a pointer to a buffer (like CU_JIT_INFO_LOG_BUFFER), you pass that pointer as the option value, but when it needs to be simple integer (like CU_JIT_MAX_REGISTERS), you cast the integer value to a void* and pass that:

```
void *optionValues[] = {
    (void*)(uintptr_t) CU_TARGET_COMPUTE_20,
};
```