# cuModuleLoadDataEx ignores all options

Tags: c++, cuda, ptx

This question is similar to [cuModuleLoadDataEx options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937250/cumoduleloaddataex-options) but I would like to bring the topic up again and in addition provide more information.

When loading a PTX string with the NV driver via cuModuleLoadDataEx it seems to ignore all options all together. I provide full working examples so that anyone interested can directly and with no effort reproduce this. First a small PTX kernel (save this as small.ptx) then the C++ program that loads the PTX kernel.

```
.version 3.1
.target sm_20, texmode_independent
.address_size 64
.entry main()
{
        ret;
}
```

main.cc

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include "cuda.h"

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  CUdevice cuDevice;
  CUcontext cuContext;

  CUfunction func;
  CUresult ret;
  CUmodule cuModule;

  cuInit(0);

  std::cout << "trying to get device 0\n";
  ret = cuDeviceGet(&cuDevice, 0);
  if (ret != CUDA_SUCCESS) { exit(1);}

  std::cout << "trying to create a context\n";
  ret = cuCtxCreate(&cuContext, 0, cuDevice);
  if (ret != CUDA_SUCCESS) { exit(1);}

  std::cout << "loading PTX string from file " << argv[1] << "\n";

  std::ifstream ptxfile( argv[1] );
  std::stringstream buffer;
  buffer << ptxfile.rdbuf();
  ptxfile.close();

  std::string ptx_kernel = buffer.str();

  std::cout << "Loading PTX kernel with driver\n" << ptx_kernel;

  const unsigned int jitNumOptions = 3;
  CUjit_option *jitOptions = new CUjit_option[jitNumOptions];
  void **jitOptVals = new void*[jitNumOptions];

  // set up size of compilation log buffer                                                                                                     
  jitOptions[0] = CU_JIT_INFO_LOG_BUFFER_SIZE_BYTES;
  int jitLogBufferSize = 1024*1024;
  jitOptVals[0] = (void *)&jitLogBufferSize;

  // set up pointer to the compilation log buffer                                                                                              
  jitOptions[1] = CU_JIT_INFO_LOG_BUFFER;
  char *jitLogBuffer = new char[jitLogBufferSize];
  jitOptVals[1] = jitLogBuffer;

  // set up wall clock time                                                                                                                    
  jitOptions[2] = CU_JIT_WALL_TIME;
  float jitTime = -2.0;
  jitOptVals[2] = &jitTime;

  ret = cuModuleLoadDataEx( &cuModule , ptx_kernel.c_str() , jitNumOptions, jitOptions, (void **)jitOptVals );
  if (ret != CUDA_SUCCESS) { exit(1);}

  std::cout << "walltime: " << jitTime << "\n";
  std::cout << std::string(jitLogBuffer) << "\n";
}
```

Build (assuming CUDA is installed under /usr/local/cuda, I use CUDA 5.0):

```
g++ -I/usr/local/cuda/include -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/ main.cc -o main -lcuda
```

If someone is able to extract any sensible information from the compilation process that would be great! The documentation of CUDA driver API where cuModuleLoadDataEx is explained (and which options it is supposed to accept) http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/index.html

If I run this, the log is empty and `jitTime` wasn't even touched by the NV driver:

```
./main small.ptx
trying to get device 0
trying to create a context
loading PTX string from file empty.ptx
Loading PTX kernel with driver
.version 3.1
.target sm_20, texmode_independent
.address_size 64
.entry main()
{
    ret;
}

walltime: -2
```

EDIT:

I managed to get the JIT compile time. However it seems that the driver expects an array of 32bit values as OptVals. Not as stated in the manual as an array of pointers (`void *`) which are on my system 64 bits. So, this works:

```
const unsigned int jitNumOptions = 1;
CUjit_option *jitOptions = new CUjit_option[jitNumOptions];
int *jitOptVals = new int[jitNumOptions];
jitOptions[0] = CU_JIT_WALL_TIME;
// here the call to cuModuleLoadDataEx
std::cout << "walltime: " << (float)jitOptions[0] << "\n";
```

I believe that it is not possible to do the same with an array of `void *`. The following code does not work:

```
const unsigned int jitNumOptions = 1;
CUjit_option *jitOptions = new CUjit_option[jitNumOptions];
void **jitOptVals = new void*[jitNumOptions];
jitOptions[0] = CU_JIT_WALL_TIME;
// here the call to cuModuleLoadDataEx
// here I also would have a problem casting a 64 bit void * to a float (32 bit)
```

**EDIT**

Looking at the JIT compilation time `jitOptVals[0]` was misleading. As mentioned in the comments, the JIT compiler caches previous translations and won't update the JIT compile time if it finds a cached compilation. Since I was looking whether this value has changed or not I assumed that the call ignores the options all together. Which it doesn't. It's works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `jitOptVals` should not contain pointers to your values, instead cast the values to `void*`:

```
// set up size of compilation log buffer
jitOptions[0] = CU_JIT_INFO_LOG_BUFFER_SIZE_BYTES;
int jitLogBufferSize = 1024*1024;
jitOptVals[0] = (void *)jitLogBufferSize;

// set up pointer to the compilation log buffer
jitOptions[1] = CU_JIT_INFO_LOG_BUFFER;
char *jitLogBuffer = new char[jitLogBufferSize];
jitOptVals[1] = jitLogBuffer;

// set up wall clock time
jitOptions[2] = CU_JIT_WALL_TIME;
float jitTime = -2.0;
//Keep jitOptVals[2] empty as it only an Output value:
//jitOptVals[2] = (void*)jitTime;
```

and after `cuModuleLoadDataEx`, you get your `jitTime` like `jitTime = (float)jitOptions[2];`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am on a 64 bit system. The compiler won't let me cast a float to a void*. Does this interface only work with 32 bit pointers?

Comment: The driver only accepts 32bit void pointers no matter if on a 32 or 64 bit system. Incredibly stupid. So, on a 64 bit system the solution is to not use **void (as indicated in the manual), but *int. They got to be kiddin.

Comment: Which of course also means you can't use it to pass in a pointer to a buffer to get the compilation log.

Comment: No, it also works on 64 bit. But for the jit-time you have to cast the 64 bit pointer first to a 32 bit integer and then read the bits as a float: int opt_int = (int)jitOptVals[2];
 float* opt_float = (float*)&opt_int;
 float jitTime = *opt_float;

Comment: Yes, I got the jit_time out. What I meant in my last comment is that passing in a 64 bit pointer to a buffer to get the log information is impossible.

Comment: It is possible. On a 32-bit system you pass 32 bit pointers, on a 64-bit system you pass 64-bit pointers. It's always a void* and never just a 32-bit int.

Comment: Your cast `int opt_int = (int)jitOptVals[2];` looses precision. This will not be right. If you are sure your pointer fits in 32bit then you should at least use a (intptr_t) cast

Comment: I think you are not trying this out but argue along the interface and assume that it's correctly implemented. Which I believe it's not for a 64 bit system.

Comment: Do the cast the way you want to do it, you only need the first 32 bits. And yes, I test the things before I post them. Take the matrixMulDrv sample from the SDK, works like a charm. A problem with your log buffer might be that you get no output, because every ptx-compilation is cached by the driver... What is the value of jitOptVals[0] after cuModuleLoadDataEx? It should be the number of written chars to the buffer.

Comment: This caching thing was a good guess. If I slightly modify the PTX string I finally get some timings out.